# get error "incorrect command line" when trying to extract 7zip archive on linux

Tags: linux, compression

I copied a large zip file to a Linux server, I didn't realise at the time that it was a 7zip file.

After some messing around I installed 7zip with "yum install p7zip" however when I try to extract the archive with

```
7za -x ./myarchive.zip
```

I get the following output

> 7-Zip (A) 4.61 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2008 Igor Pavlov  2008-11-23
>   p7zip Version 4.61 (locale=C,Utf16=off,HugeFiles=on,1 CPU)
>
> Error:
>   Incorrect command line

Google is not my friend with this error, so I thought that I would try here. Debated as to if this should be SF or SU, but as it is not my computer I think it is SFs' domain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure it takes the "-x" and not just "x"?

And why is the file a .zip instead of the 7zip extension ".7z"?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to indicate the parameters without "-"
In your case, "7za x ./myarchive.zip" is the right structure to decompress your archive